# Serverless deploy failing with + character in stackTags variable

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

In My serverless.yml file i have a StackTag variable defined as below

```
 stackTags:
    Name: My Service
    Category: Environment:${opt:stage}+Role:Application
```

So when i run `sls deploy --stage dev` in get the below error and deployment fails

Invalid stage variable value: Category: Environment:${opt:stage}+Role:Application.  Please use values with alphanumeric characters and the symbols ' ', -', '.', '_', ':', '/', '?', '&', '=', and ','.

So is this a limitation with Serverless Framework? Am able to use the same Tag via the AWS UI Console.

When i replace "+" with any other character like "." or ":" then the deploy works, it fails for "+" character

Comment: I'm confused.  It said it won't accept the plus sign so why are you still using the +?

Comment: The reason why i want to use  + is these Tags are used by other teams for their analysis. So i need to maintain the same tags. And i had been using it this way all the while, suddenly since a week or so am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a great answer, but you've hit a known and reported bug:

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/6133

> API Gateway tags setting Stage Variables not Tags

Stage variables have different limitations to tags (and specifically for your case they do not support `+`).

Looking through the releases, reverting back to version `1.14.1` may be a workaround for this.